# Grabbing lines starting with a specific word with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl

This might be trivial but I am new to Perl and need help with this. I have a huge text file containing

```
        .
        .
    TOTAL REVENUE 416917.000000 
        .
        .
        .
    TOTAL REVENUE 415870.000000
        .
        .
        .
```

I simply want to copy the lines starting with 'TOTAL' to another file.
How can I do this in Strawberry Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows?  Have you tried the 'findstr' command from a DOS prompt?  Like:

```
findstr /B "TOTAL" your_file_name > matches.txt
```

The /B modifier will match all lines that start with "TOTAL".  The '>' will save all matched lines to the 'matches.txt' file.